# Proof using chebyshev's inequality and probably markovs

Tags: probability

I have to proof that for any random variable X and $\lambda>0$ then $$P[
X − E[X] ≥ \lambda]
≤ P[
|X − E[X]| ≥ \lambda]$$

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? 

As a hint: recall that for any two events $A,B$, $P(A) \le P(A \cup B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$|X - EX| \geq \lambda \iff X - EX \geq \lambda \text{ or } EX - X \geq \lambda$

So how does $\Pr[|X - EX| \geq \lambda]$ compare to $\Pr[X - EX \geq \lambda]$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^